# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on ExternalLogin with Owin + OAuth + Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, google-authentication

My Application Hosting uses the [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to redirect all pages to HTTPS.

The problem is that the way it was configured, the ASP.Net MVC understand that the request is HTTP, even being HTTPS.

When I check the URL that goes to google authentication it is that way:

`&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%mydomain.com\signing-google`

I am trying redirect to google changing "manually" to HTTPS.

I have tried this:

```
public class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
   ...

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        if (UserId != null)
            properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;

        var owin = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();

        owin.Request.Scheme = "https"; //hotfix

        owin.Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

And this:

```
 app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Secrets.GoogleClientId,
                ClientSecret = Secrets.GoogleClientSecret,
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnApplyRedirect = async context =>
                    {
                        string redirect = context.RedirectUri;

                        redirect = redirect.Replace("redirect_uri=http", "redirect_uri=https");
                        context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The two ways are wonking and the google can redirect to my application again, however, when I try get the `loginInfo` the data is null.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            returnUrl = "~/";

        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            //always return null, if I change from HTTP to HTTPS manually
        }
```

I tried to see the `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` implementation, but I didn't find because it always return null when I do this workaround.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? i have ARR set up as a reverse proxy with SSL offloading so the ChallengeResult redirects to google using HTTP. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at different variations of the same problem, I've found a solution to this, at least in my specific scenario.

MVC hosted on AWS EB with a load balancer.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use((ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });

    // your other middleware configuration

    // app.UseFacebookAuthentication();
    // app.UseGoogleAuthentication();

    // other providers
}
```

I put the Use() function before all other configurations, it may only be necessary to place it above the OAuth provider configurations.

My guess is manipulating the `redirect_uri` directly causes issues with the signing of the callback data.

Comment: Thank you, it work for me with asp.net 4.5 and nginx reverse proxy

Comment: 6 years later, and i needed to solve the exact same problem. 
Thank you @JConstantine for the solution. it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

In your Google Developers Console you configured your "Authorized redirect URIs."

Your URI should be "**https**://[Your Domain]/signin-google"

If it is not https your site may be loosing the credential information passed back from Google because you are doing a redirect to https before the AccountController ExternalLoginCallback code is being run.